# What Oracle setting prevents open cursors from closing?

Tags: oracle, cursor

I have two Oracle 11G installations. I can run a script that imports a 37MB database into one of them with no problems (installation A). In the other (installation B), when I run the exact same script with the exact same file it gets "ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded". I increased the max open cursors to 20,000 but when the script gets to row 20,000 then it stops with the same ORA-01000 error. The installation that is working has max open cursors set to 300.

**Obviously there is no problem with the script or the SQL because it works in one Oracle database. So there must be a setting in the other Oracle instance that prevents open cursors from closing. What could it be?**

Installation A works. 
Database = Oracle Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options. Driver = Oracle JDBC driver 11.2.0.1.0.

Installation B does not work. 
Database = Oracle Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options. Driver = Oracle JDBC driver 11.2.0.3.0.

Comment: I think the question should be: "Why does Oracle opens a new cursor for (apparently) each record? You can compare all Oracle parameters with this view `SELECT * FROM V$PARAMETER`. Have a look at Oracle parameter [cursor_sharing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams035.htm)

Comment: Hi, Can you please describe how were you able to solve this problem. This will be of great help. we are also in a similar situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has been a long time. I can't remember how it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking what cursors are open in a session. If you see 10.000 statements, all alike, with open cursors, there is something wrong in the code.

I myself find the easiest way to do this:

```
connect sys

alter system flush shared_pool; /* Removes everything can be finished, the trees hinder my view of the forest. */

/* Overall overview. */
select *
from v$sqlarea

/* Open cursors per session. */

select *
from v$open_cursor
```